# Can't fill an ArrayList without an OutOfMemoryError

Tags: file, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to use a `Scanner` to read from an file but I get an `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

```java
public static void fillId() throws FileNotFoundException{
   int i = 0;
   scanner = new Scanner(file);   
   while(scanner.hasNext()){
       Ids.add(i); 
       i++;
   }
}
```

Context:
I'm trying to fill the `ArrayList` will Ids, which are `int`s, depending on how many lines the `file` has. I've tried using the debugger to see where I could've gone wrong, but everything seems fine.

Comment: Your are never reading the `next()` element. So if there is at least one element, `hasNext()` will always be `true`.

Comment: you mean i have to define when it happens to have not next element?

Comment: No, I mean you have to invoke `next()` in the loop. You are standing at an entrance and repeatedly asking whether it is possible to make a step forward, but you never move forward. So you’ll ask forever without ever reaching the wall at the end of the room.

Comment: Thanks man i got it!